# Problem proving $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_S(f(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}=\mu(S)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, sequence-of-function

Statement:
Given a measurable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a measurable function $f:S \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\gt1$ for all $x \in S$. Show that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_S(f(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}=\mu(S)$$

I have searched that there are some similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605673/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-intf1-nd-mu-mue-f) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544655/proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-int-s-f1-n-dm-ms), but they do not start from the same hyphothesis.The sequence $f_n = (f(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing and I have tried to solve it by dominated/monotone convergence, but i believe that there is something missing about the integrability of $f$. I do not know how to continue.

Comment: What's the version of the monotone and dominated convergence theorem that do you know? By hypothesis, we can see that $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so without loss of generality I will suppose that $\mu(S)<\infty$ is finite. Note that if $\mu(S)=\infty$ so the statement hold.

Comment: Since that $f: S\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function and for all $x\in S$ we have $f(x)>1$, so we have $(\sqrt[n]{f_{n}(x)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of non-negative  functions $\nearrow$.

Comment: Finally, since that $\displaystyle \int_{S}f^{\frac{1}{n}}d\mu$ so we can suppose using my first coment that $f\in L^{\frac{1}{n}}(S, \mu)$.

Comment: @АлександрПальма The sequence is decreasing, isn't it? E.g. with $f(x)=x$, $S=(1,2)$, i think that $x ≥ x^{\frac{1}{2}} ≥ x^{\frac{1}{3}}≥...$. Same with a general function if $f(x)>1$. As it is non-increasing, I can not apply monotone convergence. I know the version for measurable, increasing, nonegative sequences. I could apply it to $f - f_n$ but i know nothing about the integrability of $f$.

Comment: If a sequence $g_n$ of functions is decreasing, then $g_1 - g_n$ is increasing.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, but we can not assure that the integral of $g_1$ is finite, so I don't think we could get something from there.

Comment: So your next question should be "how can that be fixed?"

Comment: @PaulSinclair I spent a while thinking about it, but I got nothing. That is why I asked the question here.